# WebScraping with Selenium Python Question

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, popup

I have this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions
import os

os.environ['PATH'] += "C:\\Users\\czoca\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject4\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.teintes.fr/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
myelement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/p")
myelement = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Carens III")
myelement1.click()
myelement.click()
```

Everything seems ok I am following some tutorials and documentation, for the XPATH and I tried other attributes..

But I have a pop up to consent to the web terms that i have to press Autorizate. But it wont click on it. Any ideia why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMXGP.png)

It is the button "Autoriser"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.teintes.fr/'
driver.get(url)
accept_cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Autoriser']")))
accept_cookies_button.click()
```

Advices:

- Use recognizables selectors
- It is a good tip to wait for the element you will use